# Long chords in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

How do I write chords that are longer that a "1" in Lilypond? For instance, below I have a chord that spans 12/4 and where I currently have made a hack with r1. (N.C.).

```
<<
  \new ChordNames {
    \chordmode {
      c1. r1. f1. r1.
    }
  }
  \new Staff {
    \numericTimeSignature \time 12/4 \key c \major
    \relative {c'1. d1. f1. a1.}
  }
>>
```

There should be no "N.C.". I have also tried `c1. ~c1. f1. ~f1.`, but that displays the chord multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In LilyPond, the duration that takes up two whole notes is called `\breve`, therefore you can use `c\breve.` (a dotted breve). Four whole notes would be `\longa` and eight would be `\maxima`.

Another solution in this particular case is `c1.*2`. The `*2` multiplier normally modifies the duration without modifying the appearance (e.g., `c'4*2` looks like a quarter note but takes the duration of a half note). Obviously, this has no impact on chord names.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use s (space) instead of r (rest). This will not produce N.C. in the context of ChordNames.

```
\new ChordNames {
  \chordmode {
    c1. s1. f1. s1.
  }
}
```